# Hibernate: Best way of using the `SessionFactory`

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am developing a web application with pure JSP, Servlet and Hibernate. Last few days I was having a trouble with the `SessionFactory` of `Hibernate`, not knowing the best way of implementing it. In various places developers have claimed that there should be one `SessionFactory` for the application. So, I created a singleton class like below.

```
package dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class SessionFactoryBuilder
{
    private static SessionFactoryBuilder instance;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private SessionFactoryBuilder()
    {
        buildConfig();
    }

    private static void buildConfig()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public static SessionFactoryBuilder getInstance()
    {
         if(instance == null) 
         {
            instance = new SessionFactoryBuilder();

         }
      return instance;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Below is a class which uses the `SessionFactoryBuilder`.

```
public class AgentImpl implements AgentInterface
{
    SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactory = SessionFactoryBuilder.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Session openCurrentSession() {
            Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            return currentSession;
    }

    @Override
    public Transaction openTransaction(Session session) {
        Transaction beginTransaction = session.beginTransaction();
        return beginTransaction;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Agent entity, Session session) {
        session.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Agent entity, Session session) {
        session.update(entity);
    }
 }
```

Now my question is, is this is the best way of using the `SessionFactory` ? This might sound like a silly question but it will not when you think about multi threaded behavior in servlets, `Driver#Connect error` happening because of incorrect usage of session factory, various ways of implementing the singleton pattern and so on. Please provide me your advice.

Comment: Your singleton is not thread-safe. It needs to be. Read the gazillions of posts explaining how to write a thread-safe singleton.

Comment: @JBNizet : thanks for the reply. I didn't make it thread safe because 'SessionFactory' is thread safe.

Comment: The fact that SessionFactory is thread-safe doesn't prevent your thread-unsafe singleton to create two instances of SessionFactory.

Comment: @JBNizet : OK, I will make it thread safe.